# converting string to variable [python]

Tags: python, string, list

in my program, i have a list of lists that needs to be accessed based on the contents of a variable.

```
string = [
         [arg1, arg2, arg3],
         [arg1, arg2, arg3]
         ]

string2 = [
          [arg1, arg2, arg3],
          [arg1, arg2, arg3]
          ]
```

however, this will always be a string.

```
Class.variable = 'string' # this can be either 'string' or 'string2'
```

the code i have to access the list of list is

```
newVariable = Class.variable[seperateVariable][0]
```

however, this causes an error

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

i've figured out the cause of this is because Class.variable is a string and not actually a variable.

what would be the best scaling way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off with a dictionary if `Class.variable` really needs to be a string (for example because it's user input):

```
strings = { "string": [[arg1, arg2, arg3],[arg1, arg2, arg3]], 
            "string2": [[arg1, arg2, arg3],[arg1, arg2, arg3]] }
```

Now you can access `strings[separateVariable][0]`.

(In your example, you were trying to access `"string"[separateVariable][0]` which fails for sufficiently high values of `separateVariable`).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quote when assigning the string to your Class Variable. Also please refrain from name conflict with implicit types or modules

```
Class.variable = string1
```

When you are quoting the variable, its actually considered as a string rather than a variable. So the actual content of the variable is never assigned to your `Class` variable.

Comment: i wouldn't be able to do that. that variable is assigned elsewhere and i'd need it to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtins globals() or locals() depending on where 'string1' is defined so you'd do:

```
Class.variable = locals()['string']
```